# How to write operators in Reactor 3?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I've implemented a Reactor operator by implementing `org.reactivestreams.Publisher`, as you can see below. However, I wonder whether this is the *right way ™* to use Reactor. Implementing a subscriber by hand looks a bit cumbersome. And the [Operators](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Operators.html) class seems not to be helpful in this regard.

```
class MyOperator implements Publisher<Integer> {

    private final Publisher<Integer> source;

    public MyOperator(Publisher<Integer> source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    @Override
    public void subscribe(Subscriber<? super Integer> target) {
        final Subscriber<Integer> wrappedSubscriber = createSubscriber(target);
        source.subscribe(wrappedSubscriber);
    }

    private Subscriber<Integer> createSubscriber(Subscriber<? super Integer> target) {
        return new Subscriber<Integer>() {
            private Subscription subscription;

            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Subscription subscription) {
                this.subscription = subscription;
                subscription.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Integer integer) {
                target.onNext(integer + 1); // actual behaviour
                subscription.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable t) {
                target.onError(t);
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                target.onComplete();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Or is the following example the *right way ™*?

```
class MyCompactOperator implements Publisher<Integer> {

    final Flux<Integer> flux;

    public MyCompactOperator(Publisher<Integer> source) {
        flux = Flux.from(source).map(number -> number + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void subscribe(Subscriber<? super Integer> subscriber) {
        flux.subscribe(subscriber);
    }
}
```

At least this requires a lot less code.

And variant 3 with a `Flux` as source, as suggest by Simon Baslé:

```
class MyFluxOperator extends Flux<Integer> {

    private final Flux<Integer> source;

    public MyFluxOperator(Flux<Integer> source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    @Override
    public void subscribe(Subscriber<? super Integer> subscriber) {
        source.map(number -> number + 1).subscribe(subscriber);
    }
}
```

All implementations are working as expected:

```
Flux<Integer> source = Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
Flux.from(new MyOperator(source)).subscribe(System.out::println);

// for variant 3
new MyFluxOperator(source).subscribe(System.out::println);
```

I've used a `Flux` in the second line to avoid the implementation of another subscriber.

Output:

```
2
3
4
5
6
```

Questions:

- Is there something missing in my implementation?
- Is there a better way (with less code, better error handling or whatever) to implement operators in Reactor 3?
- Are there relevant functional or non-functional differences between both approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing your second option, you seem to think that you HAVE to implement a Publisher. That is definitely not the case (on the contrary). Start from a reactor Flux source (or a Publisher + Reactor's Flux.from) and simply chain in the `map`.

edit: to clarify you don't want to create any class, just do that in your main code path:

- If your `source` is already a `Flux` or `Mono`:

  ```
  Flux<Integer> incrementedSource = source.map(i -> i + 1);
  incrementedSource.subscribe(subscriber);
  ```
- If your `source` is another kind of `Publisher`:

  ```
  Flux<Integer> incrementedSource = Flux.from(source).map(i -> i + 1);
  incrementedSource.subscribe(subscriber);
  ```

The whole idea of a library like Reactor is to give you operators that you can directly compose without having to write a `Publisher`

If you want a way to mutualize code because you regularly apply a set of operators to various `Flux`, have a look at `transform` and `compose` (and the [reference documentation](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/docs/index.html#_mutualizing_operator_usage)).

Comment: Thanks. Is my 3rd approach like how you meant it? Is there a way to chain such operators from left right and not nesting them like in `new MyFluxOperator(source).subscribe(System.out::println)`?

Comment: My example is just a bit synthetic. In reality I need something more complex with operators parametrised  from the outside and chainable at runtime ...

Comment: ok so have a look at the link I provided in my edit, what you seem to need is  mutualization of the chaining of multiple existing operators ;)